# Parsing a binary tree-like JSON Object level by level in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I was messing around with binary tree ADT implementation of javascript and was wondering if someone could help me out with parsing this particular json object.

```
{"root":{"info":1,"right":{"info":3,"left":{"info":2,"count":1},"right":{"info":5,"left":{"info":4,"count":1},"count":1},"count":1},"count":1}}
```

A quick http://json.parser.online.fr/ online says that the output should be:

```
1
3
2 5
4
```

if I am to print the json level by level. "info" holds the data of the tree node, and "left" & "right" points to sub nodes. My printTreeByLevel,

```
this.printTreeByLevel = function(node){

  nodesQueue = [];
  var nodesInCurrentLevel = 1;
  var nodesInNextLevel = 0;
  nodesQueue.push(node);
  while (nodesQueue.length != 0) {
    currNode = nodesQueue[nodesQueue.length-1];
    nodesQueue.pop();
    nodesInCurrentLevel--;
    if (currNode) {
       document.getElementById("main").innerHTML =    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML + currNode.info +"   ";
      nodesQueue.push(currNode.left);
      nodesQueue.push(currNode.right);
      nodesInNextLevel += 2;
    }
    if (nodesInCurrentLevel == 0) {
      document.getElementById("main").innerHTML =    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML + "<br>"; 
      nodesInCurrentLevel = nodesInNextLevel;
      nodesInNextLevel = 0;
    }
  }
}
}
```

produces

```
1
3 5
4
2
```

Comment: Just a note: You have a plain-old JavaScript `object`, nothing to do with `JSON` which is a way of serializing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were parsing the tree in *depth-first* instead of *breath-first* and that's why the elements did not appear in the order you wanted them.

**What this means**

At every iteration you were actually getting the last inserted element. This lead to you actually printing in *depth* instead of parsing the tree in the order it was inserted (on levels).

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/duha7tx3/

And here is the piece of wrong code:

```
currNode = nodesQueue[0];
nodesQueue.splice(0, 1);
```

What I am doing here is that I am getting the first element and then removing it from the array. Parsing the tree in this way means I am visiting **all** nodes on current level **before** going to the next one. The way you did it meant that you were visiting the nodes on the **next** level before visiting the ones on the current.

Hope this answers your question.